# Selenium, JAVA - how to find such element?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver

Do you know how to find and click at an element like this:

```
<div class="offer ctrlOpenOfferInfo">
<a class="linkOffer" href="offer_view.html?id=1007"/>
<p class="photo">
<p class="name">New offer</p>
<p class="price">123</p>
<div class="rate ctrlViewRateOffer" data-value="0.0000">
<p class="date"/>
<div class="hide info">
<div class="bgInfo"/>
```

using Selenium WebDriver and using the name of the element as there are few very similiar elements on the page?

Here's what I've tired so far:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text()='New offer']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='formDevelopmentElementAdd'][text()='New offer']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='formDevelopmentElementAdd']/div/p[2][text()='New offer']")).click();
```

or:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='name'][text()='New offer']")).click();
```

or:

```
String address = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'New offer') and @class='name']")).getAttribute("href");
driver.get(baseUrl + address);
```

or:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[Text()='New offer']")).click();
```

I've tried these with text, class, xpath...

Comment: i have tried that but it is not a good idea because it is an element which i have just created and i want to open its page and every time i run the test in future i will have a different number of similiar elements on the page and i would have to count it every time and put the right number into xpath. the xpath of it is : .//*[@id='formDevelopmentElementAdd']/div[14] and 14 its number at the moment. i tried using a variable in xpath but it did not work. I tried finding its href but also did not work. no new ideas at the moment, need help...

Comment: Then I suggest use id with each element. In this case you have to implement dynamic id - means every time you add an item/element then you should generate it's id too. After that you can use `getElementById()` method.

Comment: What do you mean by **an element** which one specifically?

Comment: @Saifur Im not quite sure how to call it in English so let's say: I have a company and my whole offer (meetings, documents, ...) is available to see, buy etc. on the page I'm testing. Every offer is in a frame. I need to find the one which i have just created and for which code I added in the question. The offer name is New offer.

Comment: @VivekSingh a lot, see edited question.

Comment: are you switching to the frame?

Comment: I'm trying right now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to click the `p` tag containing `New offer`:
I would think this element is not inside an `iframe`. If so,  you must use `driver.switchTo().frame("name or xpath or css for frame locator");` first before start looking for element.
Now, how can you find that element. Consider the following options:

> Using `xpath` text based search

```
//p[.='New offer']
//to be more precise you can do
//p[@classs='name'][.='New offer']
```

You can use `By.className('name')` to identify that element even though that name does not look like unique to me

> Using `cssSelector`

`.name`

> using `nth-child()` function of `cssSelector`

`.offer.ctrlOpenOfferInfo>a>p:nth-child(2)`

Comment: is this correct?     `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.linkOffer")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='name'][.='New offer']")).click();`

Comment: Syntax is. I don't know the `html` of the page. So, not sure if the selector for `iframe` is correct or not

Comment: Ok. I see no `frame` in HTML. I used the word frame to describe the element and did not mean there is` frame` in HTML - I was not aware of the HTML meaning of the word. This is the class, my element is in: `<div class="offersList">
<form id="formDevelopmentElementAdd" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="formDevelopmentElementAdd" name="form">
<input id="formDevelopmentElementAdd-data" type="hidden" name="data">`

Comment: any chance to click the element using someting else?

Comment: Please explain something else. You mean `JavaScript`?

Comment: Well, I mean anything. I've been fighting with this for a long time and I can't find solution so I mean anything you think could help..